# removing the block/space after manipulated with position: relative

Tags: html, css

I have the 3 div with 3 different of color and a paragraph. And i do a little manipulating with the paragraph so it can be moved anywhere with

```
 p {
    width: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 350px;
  }
```

But after it moved, the problem is the last position of the block of paragraph still there and i want it to completely remove. How can i do that?
I will provide the SS so you can understand what i want.

[image: The SS is here!]

Comment: post your html.

Comment: should i? it's only 2 <div> at the first and then <p> and then the last green <div>

Comment: `The SS is here!` ... as a german, I'm a bit worried reading this ;-)

Comment: lol don't worry coz we're not living at hitler era

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `position:relative` and move the element, its first place (the space it takes) remain unchanged. As you can read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) :

> Setting the top, right, bottom, and left properties of a
>   **relatively-positioned** element will cause it to be adjusted away from
>   its normal position. **Other content will not be adjusted to fit** into
>   any gap left by the element.

```css
div.red {
  background: red;
  height:120px;
}
div.blue {
  background: blue;
  height:120px;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
</div>
<p>lorem ipusme lorem ipusmelorem ipusmelorem ipusme</p>
<div class="blue">
</div>
```

Instead you need to use `position:absolute` and add `position:relative` to the parent container to still be able to move the element relatively to its initial place.

```css
div.red {
  background: red;
  height: 120px;
}

div.blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 120px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
</div>
<div>
  <p>lorem ipusme lorem ipusmelorem ipusmelorem ipusme</p>
</div>
<div class="blue">
</div>
```

Comment: yeah that's what i mean too. So do you have any solution for that?